Django rest framework con Auth0
buenos dias. Me encuentro en un proyecto en el cual queremos integrar auth0, tenemos un backend basado en django rest freamework y un fronted basado en node.js con react.js. El requerimiento es que el usuario se loggea desde el frontend y nos envia el AccessToken y nosotros manejamos la logica para definir segun el rol que rutas mostrar. Bueno, para esto lo que hicimos fue probar a travez del postman un usuario que se logea obtenemos todos los datos de acceso:
    {
    "access_token": "token encriptada en jwt",
    "id_token": "otra token encriptada",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}

Se realiza mediante esta peticion POST con esta url: https://rubenolivero.us.auth0.com/oauth/token
Segun documentacion que encontramos hicimos esto, y es donde puede que esten mis errores:
en el archivo settings, definimos la aplicacion a incorporar.
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'auth0authorization.authentication.Auth0TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

    # auth0 settings
AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.getenv('AUTH0_DOMAIN')
AUTH0_ALGORITHMS = ['RS256']
AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE = os.getenv('AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE')
Tambien vimos alguien que lo hizo de esta manera, para que se tenga en cuenta:



    JWT_AUTH = {
     'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER':
         'auth0authorization.utils.jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler',
     'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
         'auth0authorization.utils.jwt_decode_token',
     'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
     'JWT_AUDIENCE': 'https://Elian/',
     'JWT_ISSUER': 'https://rubenolivero.us.auth0.com/',
     'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
 }

Luego se intento aplicarlo de esta forma:
import requests
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import jwt
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework.authentication import (BaseAuthentication,
                                           get_authorization_header)

from auth0authorization.models import Auth0User

User = get_user_model()
AUTH0_DOMAIN = getattr(settings, 'AUTH0_DOMAIN', 'https://drf-auth0/')


def is_valid_auth0token(token):
    # TODO: remove request and make the `json` file as part of the project to save the request time
    resp = requests.get('https://'+settings.AUTH0_DOMAIN +
                        '/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = resp.json()
    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    rsa_key = {}
    for key in jwks['keys']:
        if key['kid'] == unverified_header['kid']:
            rsa_key = {
                'kty': key['kty'],
                'kid': key['kid'],
                'use': key['use'],
                'n': key['n'],
                'e': key['e']
            }
    if rsa_key:
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token,
                rsa_key,
                algorithms=settings.AUTH0_ALGORITHMS,
                audience=settings.AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE,
                issuer='https://'+settings.AUTH0_DOMAIN+'/'
            )
            return payload, True
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('token is expired')
        except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                'incorrect claims, please check the audience and issuer'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                'Unable to parse authentication'
            )

    return {}, False


def get_auth0_user_data(token):
    url = 'https://' + settings.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/userinfo'
    params = {'access_token': token}
    resp = requests.get(url, params)
    data = resp.json()
    return data


class Auth0TokenAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    '''
    Auth0 token based authentication.
    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the 'Authorization'
    HTTP header, prepended with the string 'Bearer '.  For example:
        Authorization: Bearer <token data>
    '''

    keyword = 'Bearer'
    err_msg = 'Invalid token headers'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
            return None

        if len(auth) == 1:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(self.err_msg)

        if len(auth) > 2:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(self.err_msg)
        token = auth[1]
        return self.authenticate_credentials(token)

    def authenticate_credentials(self, token):
        payload, is_valid = is_valid_auth0token(token)
        if not is_valid:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(self.err_msg)

        auth0_username = payload['sub'].split('|')[1]
        auth0_user = Auth0User.objects.filter(username=auth0_username).last()
        if not auth0_user:
            user_data = get_auth0_user_data(token)
            email = user_data.get('email')
            if not email:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(self.err_msg)

            user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
            auth0_user = Auth0User.objects.create(
                username=auth0_username, user=user)
            auth0_user.user = user
            auth0_user.save()
        return auth0_user.user, token

y esta son las dos formas que encontramos de proteger las vistas:
    from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from auth0authorization.models import Todo
from auth0authorization.serializers import TodoSerializer


class TodoViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

y otra forma es:
 def get_token_auth_header(request):
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", None)
    parts = auth.split()
    token = parts[1]

    return token

def requires_scope(required_scope):
    """Determines if the required scope is present in the Access Token
    Args:
        required_scope (str): The scope required to access the resource
    """
    def require_scope(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            token = get_token_auth_header(args[0])
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)
            if decoded.get("scope"):
                token_scopes = decoded["scope"].split()
                for token_scope in token_scopes:
                    if token_scope == required_scope:
                        return f(*args, **kwargs)
            response = JsonResponse({'message': 'You don\'t have access to this resource'})
            response.status_code = 403
            return response
        return decorated
    return require_scope

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def public(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Hola desde un punto final público. No necesitas estar autenticado para ver esto.'})


@api_view(['GET'])
def private(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': '¡Hola desde un endpoint privado! Necesitas estar autenticado para ver esto.'})

# auth0authorization/views.py

@api_view(['GET'])
@requires_scope('read:messages')
def private_scoped(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated and have a scope of read:messages to see this.'})

@api_view(['GET'])
@requires_scope('read:messages')
def private_scoped(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated and have a scope of read:messages to see this.'})

pero bueno, al momento de realizar la peticion de esta manera:
**GET** http://192.168.0.205:3000/todo/
respuesta:
{"detail":"El token dado no es valido para ningun tipo de token","code":"token_not_valid","messages":[{"token_class":"AccessToken","token_type":"access","message":"El token es inválido o ha expirado"}]}


Agrego como es mi auth0:
https://ibb.co/M6TLN82
